# how does android app find res.layout.main.xml

Tags: android

I'm new... just finished my first eclipse/adt tutorial.

I don't see see anything in the manifest that points to res.layout.main.xml  or  res.values.strings.xml.

QUESTION: how does android find these xml's?

thanks,
Shannon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the xml files get sent to the R.java class. They're assigned specific integer IDs that can be referenced in your java code.

when you say `setContentView(R.layout.main)` you're getting the integer ID and passing it to the content view. This R class then redirects it to your xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can get to these files using the `R` class. For example when you want to set your contentview to `main.xml` you do it like this `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

if you want to reach a String from a XML you can do it like this `getResources().getString(R.string.appname);`

Also take a look at the Application Resources section of the Dev Guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Comment: When you build a project, everything from res is generated into a file called R.java